# ¿Ciclo for no me trae información en Web Scraping?

Tags: excel, vba, scraping

Estoy haciendo una macro donde necesito extraer información de una página web a través de Web Scraping y el ciclo for no me trae los objetos, alguien me podría ayudar que podría estar haciendo mal?

Acá escribo el código que estoy utilizando.

```
Set htmlims = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("product-details__title")

For Each htmlim In htmlims
    Sheets("Resultados").Cells(i, 2).Value = htmlim.innerText
Next htmlim
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.
Gracias.

Comment: Sin ver la web ni la estructura HTML del sitio, no podemos saberlo.

Comment: artículo 45 del RGPD, dice que el scraping es ilegal, cuidado con esto.

Comment: @Srsole decir que es ilegal es un simplificar un tema complejo y en el que habría que hacer muchas acotaciones, pero en todo caso RGPD hace alusión a datos de carácter personal, que viendo un poco el código por encima no parece que sea el caso. En todo caso, no esta de mas avisar que se podría incurrir en ilicitos haciendo web scraping

Comment: @Pikoh Hombre solo pone product_details, y mucho no puedes saber, pues el product detalis puede contener mil cosas. Soy conocedor de primera persona lo que es una denuncia por scraping, es algo que ocurre, todos lo ignoran, incluidos mis jefes, hasta que pasa.

Comment: ademas te paso esto, https://pi22.eu/index.php/zona-clientes/legislacion/lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-5d-de-proteccion-de-datos-personales-y-garantia-de-los-derechos-digitales/114-lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-titulo-ix-regimen-sancionador/516-lopd-y-gdd-lopdgdd-3-2018-articulo-72-infracciones-consideradas-muy-graves

Answer (score 1):

Depende de la web y de cómo funciona es recomendable añadir un sleep de un segundo para esperar a que termine de renderizarse todo